# Cant detach the main content from the preamble

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using a template issued by my university but the chapters I include of my own work aren't appearing in the contents, and the text I have uploaded is appearing with the header 'contents' (see picture). How do I include the sections in the contents and separate each section from the contents header? (Apologies I am quite new to LaTeX).

```
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering

% Set up the Title Page
\title  {The Distance to Star Forming Regions in the Milky Way Galaxy}
\authors  {\texorpdfstring
            {\href{http://martynbristow.co.uk/}{Liam Middleton}}
            {Liam Middleton}
            }
\addresses  {\groupname\\\deptname\\\univname}  % Do not change this here, instead these must be set in the "Thesis.cls" file, please look through it instead
\date       {\today}
\subject    {}
\keywords   {}

\maketitle
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\setstretch{1.5}  % It is better to have smaller font and larger line spacing than the other way round

% Define the page headers using the FancyHdr package and set up for one-sided printing
\fancyhead{}  % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage}  % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{}  % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy}  % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\include{preface}
\newpage
%\input{publications}
%\newpage
\input{acknowledgements}
\newpage
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Declaration Page required for the Thesis, your institution may give you a different text to place here
\Declaration{

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

I, Liam Middleton, declare that this thesis titled, `The Distance to Star Forming Regions in The Milky Way Galaxy' and the work presented in it are my own. I confirm that:

\begin{itemize} 
 
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where I have quoted from the work of others, the source is always given. With the exception of such quotations, this thesis is entirely my own work.
 
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] I have acknowledged all main sources of help.
\\
\end{itemize}
 
}
\clearpage  % Declaration ended, now start a new page

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% The "Funny Quote Page"
\pagestyle{empty}  % No headers or footers for the following pages

\null\vfill
% Now comes the "Funny Quote", written in italics
\textit{``Write a funny quote here.''}

\begin{flushright}
If the quote is taken from someone, their name goes here
\end{flushright}

\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\null
\clearpage  % Funny Quote page ended, start a new page
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------


\pagestyle{fancy}  %The page style headers have been "empty" all this time, now use the "fancy" headers as defined before to bring them back


%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\lhead{\emph{Contents}}  % Set the left side page header to "Contents"
\tableofcontents  % Write out the Table of Contents


% End of the pre-able, contents and lists of things
% Begin the Dedication page

\setstretch{1.3}  % Return the line spacing back to 1.3

\pagestyle{empty}  % Page style needs to be empty for this page
\dedicatory{
To my friends
\ldots}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

\clearpage
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\mainmatter   % Begin normal, numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
\pagestyle{fancy}  % Return the page headers back to the "fancy" style

% Include the chapters of the thesis, as separate files
% Just uncomment the lines as you write the chapters

\input{Chapters/Introduction}

\input{Chapters/Data Acquisition}

\input{Chapters/Methodology}

\input{Chapters/Discussion}

\input{Chapters/Conclusion}


%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Now begin the Appendices, including them as separate files

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following 'chapters' are Appendices

\input{Appendices/AppendixA}    % Appendix Title

%\input{Appendices/AppendixB} % Appendix Title

%\input{Appendices/AppendixC} % Appendix Title

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics
\backmatter

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\nocite{*}
\label{Bibliography}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}  % Change the left side page header to "Bibliography"
\bibliographystyle{mn2e} %{unsrtnat}  % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography
\bibliography{Bibliography}  % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"

\end{document}  % The End
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: contents page]

[image: introduction.txt appearing under header of contents and not showing in list of contents]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome, it is difficult to help as there are many things missing (it's your first question so do not worry about not knowing), could you please edit your code to include the following:
**a**) the `\documentclass{??}` of the document (the question marks)
**b)** relevant packages i.e. `fancyhdr`, any table of contents packages like `titletoc` you are using (do not include packages that are not relevant to your question i.e. `glossaries`, etc
**c)** Any relevant macros like `renewcommands` etc in between `\documentclass{}` and `\begin{document}`. It is very difficult to help without that.

Comment: I ran out of space above, could you also please include an example of what your `input{Chapters/Introduction}` contain in a separate code block, we could see if there is code contained within that is affecting your programme too, if it just contains text and figures etc then that is fine but I think it is necessary to see an example one as your code at the minute cannot be compiled (we don't have access to your `input` files) which makes it challenging to determine the issue.